# Magento - Validate checkbox

Tags: validation, magento1.9.2.3, checkbox

I have grid in my custom tab.

Need to validate my checkboxes, atlease select one checkbox before submitting the form.

Please have a look at attached screenshot.

[image]

help me in this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have add common hidden input field to the whole Grid checkbox column, that is below :

```
<input type="hidden" id="checkBoxesStatus" class="input required-entry" value="" />
```

and add the below script for checkboxes validation :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var validateCheckBoxes = (function() {
var checkBoxesStatus = false;
$$('#adminformsGrid tbody tr .checkbox').each(function(e) {
    if(e.checked) {
        checkBoxesStatus = true;
    }
});
if(checkBoxesStatus) {
    $('checkBoxesStatus').value = 1;
} else {
    $('checkBoxesStatus').value = '';
}
});

$$('#adminformsGrid tbody tr .checkbox').invoke('observe','click', function() {
validateCheckBoxes();
});
$$('#adminformsGrid thead tr .sp-pointer').invoke('observe','click', function() {
validateCheckBoxes();
});
```

It will work...

Answer (score 0):

You can try `validate-one-required` class.

`validate-one-required` tends for > **At least one textbox/radio element must be selected in a group**

To use the `validate-one-required` validator you must first add the class name to only one `checkbox/radio` button in the group (last one is probably best) and then place all the input elements within a parent element, for example a div element. That way the library can find all the `checkboxes/radio` buttons to check and place the validation advice element at the bottom of the parent element to make it appear after the group of `checkboxes/radio` buttons.

So you can use it like:

```
<fieldset>
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" />
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" />
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" />
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" />
    <input class="checkbox validate-one-required" type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" />
</fieldset>
```

For more check here : [Easy Validation by Prototype](https://ranawd.wordpress.com/2009/05/20/really-easy-field-validation-with-prototype/)

Comment: i want this in grid column..is there any possibilities to do in $this->addColimn()